# Search in Jquery each with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to search in a list with using each function. I am searching using data attribute. Here is the html:

```
<div class="tag_p" data-search-term="name" data-tag="apple, mango, orange, grapes"></div>
```

There are several divs like this.
I am using this jquery function to search through the div using data-search-term.

```
$('.tag_p').each(function(){
    if ($(this).filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 || searchTerm.length < 1)  {
        $(this).show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

It is working well, but I need to search through data tag attribute.
For eg. if I type in `orange` it should search in data tag & if I enter `name` it should search data-search term. I tried using this :

```
if (($(this).filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 || searchTerm.length < 1)
    || ($(this).filter('[data-tag *= ' + searchTerm+ ']').length > 0 || searchTerm.length < 1)) {
    // ...
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: This is working properly. See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keL9y4k7/)

Comment: Try this condition ` if ($(this).filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + '], [data-tag*=' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0) `

Comment: @Rohit your code works correctly, verify the searchTerm is what are you expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check both `data-search-term` and `data-tag` attributes, try this.

1. Check if search string present in either of the two attributes

   `filter('[data-search-term*="searchTerm"], [data-tag*="searchTerm"]')`
2. Check if search string present in both the two attributes

   `filter('[data-search-term*="searchTerm"][data-tag*="searchTerm"]')`

I used toggle function to get rid of the `if`, added an overlapping `if`, so that our conditions are evaluated only necessary.

```js
$('#search').on('input', function() {
  var searchTerm = $.trim(this.value);
  $('.tag_p').each(function() {
    if (searchTerm.length < 1) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).toggle($(this).filter('[data-search-term*="' + searchTerm + '"], [data-tag*="' + searchTerm + '"]').length > 0);
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tag_p" data-search-term="name" data-tag="apple, mango, orange, grapes">Name1</div>
<div class="tag_p" data-search-term="name2" data-tag="kerala, goa, delhi">Name2</div>
<div class="tag_p" data-search-term="name3" data-tag="who, what, where">Name3</div>
<div class="tag_p" data-search-term="name4" data-tag="water, oil">Name4</div>
<div class="tag_p" data-search-term="name5" data-tag="english, hindi">Name5</div>
<input type="text" id="search" value="">
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/43LtL8ms/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following selector to select all tags that have class "tag_p" and the "data-search-term" attribute is equal to your provided value:

```
$('.tag_p[data-search-term=' + searchTerm + ']');
```

And then apply show() function to show the selected elements.
So the complete function may be like this:

```
function (searchTerm) {
  $('.tag_p[data-search-term=' + searchTerm + ']').show();
}
```